# Merging data frames based on value in row and column name

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I work with financial data and try to merge two pandas data frames.

In the first data frame I have the information of company name, ticker code, and date.

```
    Date       Ticker     Company
0   2020-01-15 CHR.CO     Chr. Hansen
1   2020-01-15 PNDORA.CO  Pandora A/S
```

In my second df, I have a date and closing prices for stocks on some given dates.

```
    Date        CHR.CO       COLO-B.CO  DANSKE.CO   PNDORA.CO   VWS.CO
0   2020-01-15  89.5         89.5        187.39      54.4       552.0
1   2020-01-16  90           88.0        184.61      55.2       550.0
```

How could I merge these two data frames so I could get the closing stock price in the first dataframe?

Here's the desired output:

```
Date       Ticker     Company         Close_price
0   2020-01-15 CHR.CO     Chr. Hansen 89.5
1   2020-01-15 PNDORA.CO  Pandora A/S 54.4
```

Using the below line I merge the two dataframes on date, but also get all the tickers and the close price for all companies.

```
full = new_df.merge(stocks_close, on = "Date")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) before `merge` and also specify both columns `["Date",'Ticker']` in parameter `on`:

```
df = stocks_close.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Ticker', value_name='Close_price')
full = new_df.merge(df, on = ["Date",'Ticker'])
print (full)
         Date     Ticker      Company  Close_price
0  2020-01-15     CHR.CO  Chr. Hansen         89.5
1  2020-01-15  PNDORA.CO  Pandora A/S         54.4
```